# Is there any Lumiosity City map?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I'm searching such map with avenue names and stuff like cafes, houses and everything interactive. I'm too often lost in this city...

Comment: When you enter Lumiose city, you can see a big map of the city in the upper left corner of the upper screen. The highlighted part is where you're at. That's the closest I've found to a map. It disappears quite quickly, but you can make it reappear by changing your location on the map, like switching between alley and outer ring, for instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found a Lumiose City Map. Looks pretty complete.

[image]

[Large Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9P54.png)

Answer (score 1):

### Lumiosity City

Short baisic things list

**South Boulevard**

- Pokemon Lab
- PR Video Studio
- Coiffure Clips
- Route 4 and 5

**North Boulevard**

- Battle Institute
- Hotel Richissime
- Lumiose Station
- Route 13, 14 and 16

**Vernal Avenue** (South)

- Botique Couture
- Friseur Furfrou
- Herboriste
- Cafes
- Stone Emporium

**Estival Avenue** (South)

- Loto-ID Station
- Cafe with Roller Skaters (Tricks)
- News

**Autumnal Avenue** (North)

- Poke Ball Botique
- Juice Shoppe
- Restaurant Le Yeah (Two Stars)

**Hibernal Avenue** (North)

- Restaurant Le Wow (Three Stars)

**Centrico Plaza**

- Prism Tower
- Phil the Photo Guy

### Map description

- **Orange** is big route without name.
- **Black** are shortened avenues.
- Other colors are **Plazas**.

[image: Shopping skills]

Comment: I think it's actually Rouge (French for Red).

Comment: Definetily because the rest are all colors as well.

Comment: I think it's the word Rogue taking revenge for all the times it was misspelled as Rouge.